# ui5-deployer deploy command showing error "31merror[39m: undefined"

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to deploy an old SAP Fiori application to the on-premise SAP S/4 HANA ABAP Gateway system. The application was deployed using SAP webIDE without any error, but an error was encountered while deploying the SAP Fiori application using ui5-deployer from a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline.

Error message:

> 32minfo[39m: UI5 Deployer: Start deploying UI% sources.
> 31merror[39m: undefined

Deployment command:

```
ui5-deployer deploy --config ui5.json
```

ui5.json file:

```
{
 "cwd": "./dist"
 "files": "**/*.*"
 "server": "http://x.y.z.m"
 "client": "100"
 "user": "test"
 "pwd": "test@123"
 "language": "EN"
 "package": "ZTEST"
 "bspContainer": "ZTESTAPP"
 "bspContainerText": "App deployment"
 "transportNo": "D123456"
}
```

But the ui5-deployer undeploy command is working perfectly from the CI/CD pipeline.

```
ui5-deployer undeploy --config ui5.json
```

Message:

> UI5 deployer: start undeploying UI5 sources.
> UI5 Deployer: UI5 sources successfully undeployed.

Pipeline stage:

```
npm install ui5-nwabap-deployer-cli --save-dev
ui5-deployer undeploy --config ui5.json
sleep 30
ui5-deployer deploy --config ui5.json
```